# migrating from [Trac 1.0] to [Trac 1.4] TracError: OperationalError: no such column: description

Tags: database-migration, trac

as explained in the tile, I'm trying to migrate from Trac 1.0.11 to 1.4.2 (with SQLite backends) but get an error while performing "trac-admin [path] upgrade" command on.

> TracError: OperationalError: no such column: description

I have no idea where this description column can be and what it can be related to. Does anybody has any clue of what's going on, please?
NB: I actually migrated 2 workspaces and only on is failing; the only functional difference is that the failing one uses MultipleWorkflowPlugin, and the other one is not.

Here are the log traces for that issue:

```
2021-01-18 16:21:53,200 Trac[env] ERROR: Exception caught while checking for upgrade: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/env.py", line 868, in open_environment
    needs_upgrade = env.needs_upgrade()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/env.py", line 747, in needs_upgrade
    for participant in self.setup_participants:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/core.py", line 95, in extensions
    components = [component.compmgr[cls] for cls in classes]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/core.py", line 238, in __getitem__
    component = cls(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/core.py", line 157, in __call__
    self.__init__()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/multipleworkflow/workflow.py", line 113, in __init__
    for t in self._ticket_types + ['default']:
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/multipleworkflow/workflow.py", line 122, in _ticket_types
    return [enum.name for enum in model.Type.select(self.env)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/ticket/model.py", line 878, in select
    (cls.type,)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/db/util.py", line 129, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, params if params is not None else [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/db/util.py", line 62, in execute
    r = self.cursor.execute(sql_escape_percent(sql), args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/db/sqlite_backend.py", line 87, in execute
    result = PyFormatCursor.execute(self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/db/sqlite_backend.py", line 63, in execute
    args or [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trac/db/sqlite_backend.py", line 54, in _rollback_on_error
    return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
OperationalError: no such column: description
```

PS: same issue for databases previously migrated to 1.0.13 version.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: An [upgrade step](https://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.4.2/trac/upgrades/db44.py) adds the `description` column to the enum tables. Is there a traceback in the log file that might provide more information?

Comment: Thanks for that pointer @RjOllos but I'm struggling with how to make it work. Do I just have to modify the Python script somewhere in order to make it work? Or is this a patch maybe? I also added my traces above, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code from the plugin has been fixed last week. Thx
https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/13943

Answer (score 2):

This is some behavior that I haven't seen before, but I think it makes sense.

**Workaround**:

1. Disable MultipleWorkflowPlugin
2. run `upgrade`
3. Enable MultipleWorkflowPlugin.

The components are loaded when opening the environment on the execution of `upgrade`. When the MultipleWorkflowPlugin component is initialized it attempts to fetch all of the enums, which executes SQL that queries the `description` column. The `description` column doesn't exist until `upgrade` finishes, so an error results.

Edit: This issue should be fixed in the latest version of MultipleWorkflowPlugin, see [#13943](https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/13943).